# chrome plays mp3 in base64 format in android 4.0 up without sound

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

The following snippet plays well in chrome pc version.

```
var base64Data=results.rows.item(0).vocData; //mp3 in base64 format fetched from webSQL
audioPlayer.src ='data:audio/mp3;base64,'+base64Data; 
audioPlayer.load();
audioPlayer.play();
```

However, when I played it in chrome for Android, it did play without error (audioPlayer.error=null),but without any sound.
Does anyone know what's wrong with the codes, or is there any limitation under Android 4.0.4?
is there any workaound? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is most certainly a bug. Any time that you have it working on desktop and it fails to work on Chrome for Android that it is 99.5% likely to be a bug.

I have raised the bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253466 with a demo of the error here: http://jsbin.com/ajocid/latest

Right now there are no workarounds because you can't even load it into a blob and attach it.  The only potential solution is to save it up to a server somewhere and then use that URI.... which is less than optimal.